# Trying to display pasted experiences with a foreach in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display in an HTML div each element of a tab for a Wordpress plugin.

Here is the function i call in my page :

```
function past_experiences() {
    $past_experience = get_user_meta($current_user_id, 'experiences', true);
    foreach ($past_experience as $key) {
        ?>
        <div class="past_experiences"> <?= print_r($key['new_experience_team']); ?> </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

and here is what my 'get_user_meta($current_user_id, 'experiences', true)' looks like when i print it (out of the function) :

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [new_experience_team] => fhbjdshj
            [new_experience_role] => fdjhsfbkq
            [new_experience_description] => fbdsbq
            [new_experience_palmares] => fbdhsjqfbk
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [new_experience_team] => Hello
            [new_experience_role] => Hello
            [new_experience_description] => Hello
            [new_experience_palmares] => Hello
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [new_experience_team] => Hi
            [new_experience_role] => Hi
            [new_experience_description] => Hi
            [new_experience_palmares] => Hi
        )

)
```

And now the error :

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

EDIT (SOLUTION) :

In fact, the problem was when a tried to call the function in the HTML. By parsing the function content directly in my div, it worked (so in the same file, not another one. Here is so the final result :

```
<div class="experiences_container">
    <?php 
    if (!empty($experiences)) {
        foreach ($experiences as $key) {
        ?>
            <div class="past_experience">
                <div class="experience_header">
                    <div>
                        <label for="team">Nom de l'équipe</label>
                            <input class="team" name="team" value="<?= $key['new_experience_team'];?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="role">Rôle dans l'équipe</label>
                            <input class="role" name="role" value="<?= $key['new_experience_role'];?>"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="experience_textarea">
                    <label for="description">Description du rôle</label>
                    <textarea class="description" name="description"><?= $key['new_experience_description']; ?></textarea>

                    <label for="palmares">Palmarés avec l'équipe</label>
                    <textarea class="palmares" name="palmares"><?= $key['new_experience_palmares']; ?></textarea>
                </div>

            </div>  
        <?php
        } 
    } else {
    ?>
    <div><p>Vous n'avez encore rentré aucune expérience</p></div>
    <?php 
}?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here 's a quote from the WordPress Codex:

> Return #Return
>
> (mixed) Will be an array if $single is false. Will be value of meta data field if $single is true.

Your code is - following to the wordpress documentation - returning a value and not an array. You have to set the last parameter to `false` to retrieve an array.

```
$result = get_user_meta($current_user_id, 'experiences', false);
```

Further information for the `get_user_meta` function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/

Comment: That's okay i found the solution ! In fact by adding the function content in the main php file it works so... I'll do that way ;)

Comment: It would be kind to post your solution, so that others, who have the same issue, can find help here.